# Comparing complex number (again)

Tags: complex-numbers, order-theory

I've read other posts about comparing complex numbers, but I didn't find an answer for this: is it possible to define a $\leq$ relation such as:
$$
a+bi \leq c+id \iff b = d \quad\text{ and }\quad a \leq c.
$$
This means that for any complex number, such as $a = 2+3i$, and $b = 1+4i$ then $a \leq b$ will be false, but so is $b \leq a$. Is that okay, or does having $a \leq b$ being false implies that $b \leq a$ (or $a > b$) should always be true ?

Comment: Nope! You can't order impose an order on $\mathbb{C}$. The Boas text on complex analysis describes this... I think.

Comment: You might find the [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) interesting, where it talks about posets (Partially Ordered SETS). What everyone keeps insisting on is that you can't have a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) on the complex numbers (I'm guessing you already knew this from the other posts).

Comment: We can't define order on the complex numbers like we do the reals, but if you wanted to, you **can** compare their absolute values, which are just their distances from the origin on the complex plane

Comment: You can define anything you want.  And, yes, that is an order.  But it is not an ordered *field* (which requires that $0\ge a; 0\ge b \implies a*b \ge 0$.)  Making C an ordered field is impossible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof of Non-Ordering of Complex Field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181720/proof-of-non-ordering-of-complex-field)

Comment: It's not a *total* order.  as $a \not \le b$ and $a \ne b$ and $b \not \le a$.  That's not possible for a *total* order.  You can define the lexigraphical order as $a+bi \le c + di \iff (a < c) OR (a=c; b \le d)$.  But this will not make an ordered FIELD.  It finding an order that makes C and ordered FIELD that is impossible.  An ordered field requires $x \ge 0;y\ge 0\implies xy \ge 0$.  That is impossible on C because that would mean $z^2 \ge 0$ for all $z$.  So both $1^2 = 1$ and $i^2 = -1$ must both be $\ge 0$ and that is impossible.

Comment: Recall: $\Bbb{C}$ is not totally ordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order that you suggest is indeed an order, but a [*partial order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), meaning that two complex numbers are not necessarily comparable. In fact, it is isomorphic to a [*product order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_order), if we use the usual order for real parts, and set all imaginary parts incomparable.

An order such that all elements are comparable (that is, at least one of $a \leq b$ and $b \leq a$ is true) is called a [*linear order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). The usual order on $\mathbb R$ is linear, the one you suggest for $\mathbb C$ is not. Whether one needs a linear order or a general partial order depends on the context.

When one says that there is no order in $\mathbb C$, what is meant is that no order can [*respect the algebraic structure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field). This is easily seen: $-1$ is less than $0$ in any ordered field, and $x^2$ is always $\geq 0$, so in $\mathbb C$ we must have $i^2 \geq 0$ and $-1<0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Isn't it a totatal order?  Given $a + bi$ and $c + di$ either i)$a=c;b=d$  ii)$a<c$ or $a=c$ and $b<d$ or iii) $a >c$ or $a=c$ and $b > d$.  Those are the three only mutually exclusive options.  But what it isn't is an ordered *field* so that $a\ge 0; b\ge 0$ implies $ab \ge 0$.

Comment: @fleablood In the order suggested by OP two complex numbers $a+bi$ and $c+di$ are comparable ***only if*** $b=d$. Thus, it cannot be total.

Comment: Oh... you are right.  I assumed this was the lexagraphical order in that $a + bi \le c + di$ if either $a < c$ or $a=c$ and $b \le d$.  That *would* be a total order.  But One in which $i > 0$ and $i^2 < 0$ (which prevents $\mathbb C$ from being an ordered *field*).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is an order partial and it would even be a total order if you extended it to allow $a + bi \le c + di$ if either $a < b$  or if $a = b$ and $c \le d$.  However it is not an order than allows $\mathbb C$ to be an ordered *field*.

An ordered field is a field with an order but *ALSO* that has the axioms that i) $a > b\implies a+c > b+c$  and that ii) $a > 0$ and $b > 0\implies ab > 0$.

This order does not satisify those conditions:  $0 + i > 0$ but $(0+i)(0+i) = -1 < 0$.

And it is *impossible* to find an order than will allow $\mathbb C$ to be an ordered field.  In short $a > 0\implies a^2 > 0$ and and $a = 0 \implies a^2 = 0$ and (although this must be proven) $a < 0 \implies -a > 0 \implies a^2 = (-a)^2 > 0$.  But in $\mathbb C$ we have $i^2 = -1$ and $1^2 = 1$ so we must have $1 > 0$ and $-1 > 0$ and that is (again it must be proven) is impossible.