# "$\mathbb{R}^2$ can't be totally ordered" (nicely)

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I have often heard (both online and in person) people say that "$\mathbb{R}^2$ can't be totally ordered." I would like to understand this statement.

Of course, on the face of it, this is false: Pick your favorite bijection $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and define $x \leq y$ iff $f(x) \leq f(y)$.

When I bring this up, people usually dismiss it, saying it isn't "nice" enough. This is fair, but now leaves me with the question of what a "nice" ordering would look like.

Other questions on this site (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181720/proof-of-non-ordering-of-complex-field?rq=1)) show that there is no ordering which makes $\mathbb{C}$ an ordered field. I find this answer somewhat unsatisfying. I don't need to appeal to the algebraic structure of $\mathbb{R}$ to give it a "nice" ordering. Furthermore, I would like to be able to extend this notion of a "nice ordering" to other topological spaces that don't admit field structures: does $\mathbb{R}^3$ have a "nice" ordering? how about $S^1$?

Here's a definition I came up with: a total ordering on a topological space $X$ is "nice" if for every $x < y$, there are neighborhoods $U_x \ni x$ and $U_y \ni y$ so that for all $a \in U_x$ and $b \in U_y$, we have $a < b$.

So the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ is "nice," but (for all $f$ I can think of) the ordering of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given above isn't.

I've tried proving that $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S^1$ can't be given a nice total ordering under this definition, but have had some difficulty.

Questions:

1. Is there an established notion of a "nice" ordering on a topological space?
2. How can you prove that $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or $S^1$) can't be totally ordered nicely? (either with my definition or someone else's, if it exists)

Comment: Could you give an example of one of your "favorite bijections"?

Comment: Your definition seems to boil down to: An ordering is nice if the order topology is coarser than the given topology. I haven't run through the details, though, so you might want to check whether that's really equivalent.

Comment: It also looks equivalent to saying the relation $<$ is an open subset of $X \times X$.

Comment: On the other hand, if you require order topology to be *stronger* than the given topology, then both $S^1$ and $R^2$ admit a compatible order topology.

Comment: "I have often heard (both online and in person) people say that "R2 can't be totally ordered.""  I think they are simply  misparaphrasing.  Is suspect mean $\mathbb R^2$ can't be an ordered field and even that is false and they actually mean with addition and multiplication defined as they are in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Let's put @fleabood's focus on multiplication to one side for a moment. I think the criterion people normally have in mind is $a<b\implies a+c<b+c$. I don't think this can work for a total ordering on $\Bbb R^2$, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: The lexicographic order $(x,y) < (z,w)$ if $x<z$ or $x=z, y < w$, satisfies $a<b\implies a+c<b+c$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not seen a standard definition of a nice total ordering, but I like the one you provided.

Neither $\mathbb{R}^2$ nor $S^1$ admit a nice ordering by your definition. The proof is straightforward:

**Claim 1:** In a topological space $X$ with a nice total ordering $<$, for all $x\in X$ the sets $\{y \mid y<x\}$ and $\{y \mid y> x\}$ are open.

**Claim 2:** For $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ or $X=S^1$, there is no way to write $X=A\cup B\cup\{x\}$ for disjoint nonempty open sets $A,B$.

The proof of each claim is straightforward: For the first, note that the set $\{y\mid y<x\}$ can be written as a union of open balls around all points inside itself, and similarly for $\{y \mid y>x\}$. For the second, observe that the compliment of a singleton set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or in $S^1$ is connected.

Comment: In claim 2, you need to say disjoint *nonempty* open sets, and then finishing off the proof requires a tiny bit more.

Comment: Correct. This is just a sketch and I was leaving it to the reader to flush out details. It is clear that you cannot have more than one point that is greater than everything else in the space for any total order.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a point $x_0 \in X$ such that $X \setminus \{ x_0 \}$ is connected.  Then under your definition of a "nice" total order, $\{ x \in X \mid x < x_0 \}$ and $\{ x \in X \mid x_0 < x \}$ will be a partition of $X \setminus \{ x_0 \}$ into two disjoint open subsets; therefore, one of them must be the whole subspace $X \setminus \{ x_0 \}$.  In other words, $x_0$ must be either a maximum or a minimum element of $X$ under the given order.

Now, if you can find at least three distinct points $x_0, x_1, x_2$ such that $X \setminus \{ x_i \}$ is connected for each $i \in \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$, then you will get a contradiction.  This is the case both for $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and for $X = S^1$.

Comment: Nice & simple..............

Answer (score 1):

There is a notion of a GO-space (generalised ordered space), i.e. a topological space $(X,\tau)$ such that $X$ has a linear order such that the order topology induced by $<$ is a subset of $\tau$ and $\tau$ has a base of order-convex sets ($A \subseteq X$ is order convex iff $\forall x,y \in A:\forall z \in X: x \le z \le y \to z \in A$).

All LOTS (linearly ordered topolgoical spaces) $X$ (where $X$ has the order topology w.r.t. some linear order $<$) are GO-spaces as the order-topology base (of segments and intervals) is order convex. The Sorgenfrey line ($\Bbb R$ in the topology with base $\{[a,b)\mid a < b \in \Bbb R\}$) is a standard example of a GO-space (that cannot be a LOTS, by deeper results).

$\Bbb R^2$ cannot be a GO-space (which I take as an interpretation of "can be nicely ordered topologically") because in a connected GO-space, all but two of its points are cutpoints (removing them makes the remainder disconnected), or because $\dim(X) \le 1$ for all GO-spaces, and $\dim(\Bbb R^2)=2$ and the plane has no cutpoints.  $S^1$ also has no cutpoints, so is no GO-space either.